# Cannot add apple id to Visual Studio Mac

Tags: ios, macos, visual-studio, apple-id

[image: If I try to log in nothing happens. Screen just goes away doing nothing with "Sign in" button]

Yesterday everything worked. I have already made three flight test versions for beta testing. When I tried today debuging app with an iPhone I got 35 (failed to codesign) errors and Apple ID is now missing. XCode updated today but I have no idea what it did. I only use Visual Studio Mac both Android and iOS development.

Any suggestions how I get my Apple ID back to account list?